# getting error "Could not find stored procedure 'sp_OACreate'" in Sql Azure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

When I try to execute the `sp_OACreate` stored procedure in SQL azure database. I am getting following error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'sp_OACreate'

in SQL Azure.

Can anyone tell me how to execute the OLE automation methods like `sp_OACreate` in SQL Azure.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Copied & Formatted from OPs answer (which should have been an edit):

I am trying to hit the google map services to get the co-orinates(Latitude & Longitude) of any address. I am executing below sql queries. Its working fine in SQL server 2005 but its giving error in SQL Azure 2008.Plz see below:-(Please suggest some alternate for this)

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
Postal VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ZipCode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Status SMALLINT,
Accuracy TINYINT,
Lat DECIMAL(9, 6),
Lon DECIMAL(9, 6),
CreDate DATETIME
) 

INSERT @Sample
SELECT 'One Microsoft Way', '98052', 'Redmond, WA', 'USA',null,1,0,0,getdate() UNION ALL
SELECT '170 W. Tasman Dr.', '95134', 'San Jose, CA', 'USA',null,1,0,0,getdate() UNION ALL
SELECT '500 Oracle Parkway', '94065', 'Redwood Shores, CA', 'USA',null,1,0,0,getdate()

select * from @Sample

-- Initialize
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(300),
@win INT,
@hr INT,
@Text VARCHAR(8000),
@RowID int,
@Status smallint,
@Accuracy tinyint,
@Lon decimal(9, 6),
@Lat decimal(9, 6)

SELECT @RowID = MIN(RowID) FROM @Sample WHERE Status IS NULL

WHILE @RowID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @url = 'q=' + Postal + '+' + ZipCode + '+' + City + '+' + Country
    FROM @Sample
    WHERE RowID = @RowID

    SET @url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?' + @url
    SET @url = @url + '&output=csv&key={your google api key here}'

    EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @win OUT
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false'
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Send'
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText', @Text OUT
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

    EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @win 
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

    SET @Text = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Text, '.', '#'), ',', '.')
    SELECT @Status = PARSENAME(@Text, 4),
        @Accuracy = PARSENAME(@Text, 3),
        @Lat = REPLACE(PARSENAME(@Text, 2), '#', '.'),
        @Lon = REPLACE(PARSENAME(@Text, 1), '#', '.')

    UPDATE @Sample
    SET Accuracy = @Accuracy,
        Lat = @Lat,
        Lon = @Lon,
        Status = @Status,
        CreDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE RowID = @RowID

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.010'

    SELECT @RowID = MIN(RowID)
    FROM @Sample
    WHERE Status IS NULL

END

SELECT * FROM @Sample

--If Above not executing then first execute below 
--sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; 
--GO RECONFIGURE; 
--
--GO 
--
--sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1; GO RECONFIGURE; 
--
--GO
```

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what you were trying to achieve here - you're obviously trying to use a COM component - is it a common component that we might be able to suggest alternatives for?

Answer (score 2):

There's no means to call out to web services from within SQL Azure - you'll have to move such calls up into code which is running on a Windows Azure (as opposed to SQL Azure) service, and you won't be writing it in Transact SQL.

Answer (score 1):

sp_OACreate is an automation stored procedure and is not available in SQL Azure Database

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336237.aspx

I would be very surprised if there are any workarounds.

Comment: I have described my problem, plz check and suggest some alternate for this.

Comment: Don't know. Don't think there is one other than already suggested. Move the logic out of SQL Azure.